# web app back button not working

Tags: iphone, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I have a webapp used by jquery mobile, there is lots of pages this webapp. also added home screen button its feel like native app fullscreen, so i used common header for each pages, i don't want duplicate header every pages. there is a "Back" button this header, used following codes

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="g" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a onclick=history.back() data-icon="back" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button">Back</a>
</div>
```

i used php cookies store function also each pages, that point when user resume this webapp return to previous position...

my problem is when user come back previous position my back button not working, is it possible to fix.? or iPhone not allow this function for webapp.?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you set `onclick=history.back()` manually?

> The framework automatically generates a "back" button on a header when the page plugin's addBackBtn option is true.

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html (jump to "Adding Back buttons")

#### My own experience

I never ran into trouble with automatically generates back buttons on iPhone in my jQuery Mobile projects.

Comment: its a right way, but for my project its not possible when resume webapp... its not wokring... when running mobile safari its working, but when i tried fullscreen mode its not working, any idea.?